# Why `FnMut` closure does not allow shared reference to captured variable to escape?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, ownership

I'm trying to understand why a shared reference `&s` doesn't work here. As of my understanding, the closure passed to `map` owns `s` so it should be ok to return something that has shared reference to `s`. It does not try to move `s` multiple times or produce multiple mutable references here.
So why the error? Sorry if the code doesn't seem to make sense, it's just used to serve as an example!

```
    fn take_ref_produce_impl_trait(s: &str) -> impl IntoIterator<Item=String> + '_ {
        (0..s.len()).map(move |it| s[it..it+1].to_string())
    }

    fn produce_stream() {
        let s = "bbb".to_string();
        (1..3)
            .map(move |_| {
                take_ref_produce_impl_trait(&s)
            });
    }
```

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src\experiments\closure.rs:61:17
   |
58 |         let s = "bbb".to_string();
   |             - variable defined here
59 |         (1..3)
60 |             .map(move |_| {
   |                         - inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
61 |                 take_ref_produce_impl_trait(&s)
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-^
   |                 |                            |
   |                 |                            variable captured here
   |                 returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

----- UPDATE -----

Sorry for this but here is another example which lead to similar error, in fact, the example above would report the same error if `produce_stream` try to return the thing it dropped.

So if the reason that lead to the previous error was because the closure can be dropped before the iterators, then would it be for the same reason in this case?

If `Then` is the stream and its field `f` is the closure we passed to `then`, then the closure is not dropped while the stream try to produce its items. However the item is a future, which is placed in the `future` field. Is it because the future can be evaluated after `Then` is dropped?

**The `Then` struct**

```
pin_project! {
    /// Stream for the [`then`](super::StreamExt::then) method.
    #[must_use = "streams do nothing unless polled"]
    pub struct Then<St, Fut, F> {
        #[pin]
        stream: St,
        #[pin]
        future: Option<Fut>,
        f: F,
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
    use futures::{StreamExt, Stream};
    use futures::{stream};

    async fn take_ref_produce_impl_trait_v2(s: &str) -> impl Stream<Item=String> + '_ {
        stream::iter(0..s.len()).map(move |it| s[it..it+1].to_string())
    }

    async fn produce_stream_v2() -> impl Stream<Item=String> {
        let s = "bbb".to_string();
        stream::iter(1..3)
            .then(move |_| {
                take_ref_produce_impl_trait_v2(&s)
            })
            .flatten()
    }
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\experiments\closure.rs:73:48
   |
73 |                 take_ref_produce_impl_trait_v2(&s)
   |                                                ^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'_` as defined on the body at 72:19...
  --> src\experiments\closure.rs:72:19
   |
72 |             .then(move |_| {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that closure can access `s`
  --> src\experiments\closure.rs:73:48
   |
73 |                 take_ref_produce_impl_trait_v2(&s)
   |                                                ^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that return value is valid for the call
  --> src\experiments\closure.rs:69:37
   |
69 |     async fn produce_stream_v2() -> impl Stream<Item=String> {
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you `.collect()`ed the iterator in `produce_stream` instead of dropping it. Then you would have a collection of `impl IntoIterator<Item=String> + '_`.

But those iterators, with their inferred `'_` lifetime, borrow from `s`, which is dropped when `produce_stream`'s `map` closure is. That is, the closure is returning references to a string it owns, but the references outlive the closure.

If you change the closure to *not* be a `move` closure, then it should compile because the closure and the overall iterator now borrows from the local variable `s`.

But you won't be able to return that iterator from `produce_stream`,  if that's what you were hoping to do; in that case you'd need to arrange for `take_ref_produce_impl_trait` to return an iterator that *owns* the string data it's accessing (or perhaps an `Rc` of it), so that the iterator has no lifetime requirement.

Comment: thanks for the quick response and you've explained it well. But do you mind I bother you with a more complicated example before giving you the credit? I guess I shouldn't change the OP in this way, sorry for that! I've updated the new example in the OP.

Comment: @Rafoul I'm sorry, but I am not familiar with streams and I can't give you a good answer in that case. And you are correct to think that you should not change a question in that kind of way.

Comment: Never mind, you've already answered the question and helped me to look in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second example I added, I did some searching and I'd like to share what I've found.

In this [link](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/can-a-closures-return-value-borrow-from-a-captured-variable/7982/4) I found a comment which I think is the ultimate answer to all the questions raised here, I quote it as follows,

> I don’t think it’s possible with how the FnMut trait is defined:
>
> fn call_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
>
> The &'a mut self argument is restricted to lifetime 'a, chosen freely
> by the caller. There is no way for Self::Output to declare dependence
> on the lifetime 'a. You can’t really say type Output = &'a i32 since
> the 'a isn’t even in scope yet!

So in short, based on the trait definition of `FnMut`, its `Output` has nothing to do with the lifetime of the closure itself. So there is no way to say that the `FnMut` closure will outlive the thing it produces in Rust.